# c# passing dblink to parameterized oracle query and connection string

Tags: c#, oracle, c#-4.0, parameterized-query

to avoid sql injection I am using parameterized oracle query, but i  want to know 
how I  can pass `DBlink` to the table and to the `connection string` ? 
as shown below

```
SELECT a.column1, a.column2,
             b.column3,a.column4,
             b.column5
  FROM SB_ACCOUNTS@dblink A, SB_CLIENTS@dblink B
 WHERE A.column1= B.column1
     AND column1=:P_PARAM;
```

and here is how i am passing dblink within the connection string from `combobox`

```
string dblink = "AB_" + CBCode.SelectedValue.ToString();
string connstr = @"Data Source=ORCL; User Id=" + dblink + "; password=pwd;";
```

i know how to pass Oracle Parameter within the query but hwo to do it with dblink and connection string ?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":P_PARAM", OracleDbType.Int64)).Value = Convert.ToInt64(Textbox.Text);
```

in other word how to change the dblink at runtime?

Comment: You can't pass the table itself as a parameter in any database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos not the table name i want to pass the dblink the table name is static wihtin the query but i need to change the dblink at runtime so I am passing it as variable but that not good am I right ?

Comment: In 2004 you [would have had to use dynamic sql](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:17321882687949) and it wouldn't be a surprise if that was still the case.

Comment: @stuartd if you mean vs 2004 then I am using visual studio 2010 does same thing apply on vs 2004 ?

Comment: I mean the article I linked to was written in the year 2004, sorry.

Comment: @stuartd un thanks my friend i have searched before posting and read that article...